# General solution $y_{t+2}+y_{t+1}-2y_t=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, fibonacci-numbers

I would like to ask if there is a way to get a General solution for $y_{t+2}+y_{t+1}-2y_t=3$ without using the characteristic polynomial approach (similar to solving Fibonacci Equation) ? That would help me a lot.

Comment: How do you solve the Fibonacci recursion without the golden mean, i.e., the roots of the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 2):

As one can rewrite the left side as
$$
(y_{t+2}+2y_{t+1})-(y_{t+1}+2y_{t})=3 
\\~\\ \iff
(y_{t+2}+2y_{t+1}-3(t+1))-(y_{t+1}+2y_{t}-3t)=0
$$
one gets as first reduction
$$
y_{t+1}+2y_{t}=3t+(y_{1}+2y_{0})
$$
which now is a first order recursion.

Set now $u_t=(-\frac12)^t·y_t$ to find
$$
u_{t+1}=u_t+(-\frac12)^{t+1}·(3t+y_{1}+2y_{0})
$$
which now amounts to the summation of geometric and derived sequences.

Comment: Many thanks. How did you derive the first reduction?

Comment: One easily sees $1+1-2=0$ from which it follows that the left side can be arranged in simple differences, $(y_{t+2}-y_{t+1})+2(y_{t+1}-y_t)$. Then rearrange that  to get a difference of similar terms. Note that this is just a consequence that the easily seen eigenvalues are $1$ and $-2$.